# How to select value from first and second row

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to select data from table
suppose we have a table

table Temp

```
sequence_number | breakdown_number | physical_account | logical_account | debit_amount | credit_amount
----------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------+--------------+---------------
     1          |      1           |       10001      |         10      |            0
     2          |      1           |       0011       |         10      |            0
```

Now I have to select physical_account from 1st row and logical account from second row and insert it into another table in single row based on the breakdown number.

How can I do this ?

Comment: What if you had more than two rows? Is the question properly representative of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that `sequence_number` actually provides the ordering of the rows and you want to do this for each `breakdown_number`.  The most accurate method is probably to use variables:

```
INSERT INTO second_table(physical_account, logical_account)
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 1 THEN t.physical_account END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN seqnum = 2 THEN t.logical_account END)
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                 (@rn := if(@b = t.breakdown_number, @rn + 1,
                            if(@b := t.breakdown_number, 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as seqnum
          FROM Temp t CROSS JOIN
               (SELECT @rn := 0, @b := -1) params
          ORDER BY t.breakdown_number, t.sequence_number
         ) t
    WHERE rn IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY t.breakdown_number;
```

If the `sequence_number` restarts at 1 for each `breakdown_number`, then the subquery and variables are not needed:

```
INSERT INTO second_table(physical_account, logical_account)
    SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN t.sequence_number = 1 THEN t.physical_account END),
           MAX(CASE WHEN t.sequence_number = 2 THEN t.logical_account END)
    FROM Temp t
    WHERE t.sequence_number IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY t.breakdown_number;
```

Finally, in some cases, you can just use a hack:

```
INSERT INTO second_table(physical_account, logical_account)
    SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.physical_account), ',', 1),
           SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(t.logical_account), ',', 2), ',', -1)
    FROM Temp t
    WHERE t.sequence_number IN (1, 2)
    GROUP BY t.breakdown_number;
```

Notes about this approach:

- It converts the accounts to strings, if they are of some other time.
- `group_concat()` has a (configurable) maximum length, so if there are many records for a given `breakdown_number`, then you can get a run-time error.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query in the select with [`LIMIT OFFSET`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select_limit.asp):

```
INSERT INTO second_table (physical_account, logical_account)
SELECT t.physical_account,
       (SELECT s.logical_account FROM temp s
        ORDER BY s.breakdown_number
        LIMIT 1,1) 
FROM Temp t
ORDER BY t.breakdown_number
LIMIT 1
```

This will select the first and second values based on `breakdown_number` on `ACSENDING` order.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @physical_account varchar(30); /*Data Type as required*/
DECLARE @logical_account varchar(30);
SELECT @physical_account=physical_account FROM Temp WHERE logical_account=NULL AND physical_account='10001'
SELECT @logical_account=logical_account FROM Temp WHERE logical_account='0011' AND physical_account=NULL
INSERT INTO Table_New(physical_account, logical_account) VALUES(@physical_account, @logical_account);
```